# Recursion using Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I'm still trying to wrap my ahead around recursion and just when I think I'm starting to understand it a problem presents itself and I have no clue what to do.

The problem is:

Catsylvanian money is a strange thing: they have a coin for every denomination (including zero!). A wonky change machine in Catsylvania takes any coin of value N and returns 3 new coins, valued at N/2, N/3 and N/4 (rounding down).

Write a function `wonkyCoins(num)`that returns the number of coins you are left with if you take all non-zero coins and keep feeding them back into the machine until you are left with only zero-value coins.

The solution I came up with (doesn't work, infinite loop) is:

```
function wonkyCoins(num){
  if (num == 0){
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return (wonkyCoins(num/4) + wonkyCoins(num/3) + wonkyCoins(num/2));
  }
}
```

Any help you guys can contribute would be great!

Comment: What is the input and expected output?

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem. Your recursive function should always be able to stop recursing, or have a "base case" conditional. So far, the only way to get out of your recursion is when num == 0. Think about what you need to change to make the recursion end in other cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not rounding down, like your requirements state!

```
function wonkyCoins(num){
  num = Math.floor(num); //round num down to the nearest integer
  if (num == 0){
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return (wonkyCoins(num/4) + wonkyCoins(num/3) + wonkyCoins(num/2));
  }
}
```

When you don't round down, the integer division gives you floating point numbers, so they'll never equal 0.

Answer (score 0):

your solution is pretty close, except for the fact that javascript will be converting these numbers to floating point representations (therefore you never actually reach zero)

One possible way to workaround this problem is to force num to be a integer value prior to the check for zero

another possible solution would be to check for < 0.5 or some other threshold value.